# Como pasar una variable de un archivo js a otro archivo js, me da null el localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, local-storage

Quiero pasar una variable de un JavaScript a otro y lo he intentado de todas las formas posibles, lo único que he obtenido una respuesta ha sido con localstorage, aunque cuando se la pasó al otro archivo recibo null y no entiendo porque, estoy utilizando XAMPP para esto, si conocéis una forma simple de hacer esto os lo agradecería.

En el primer archivo de JavaScript tengo lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

//Aquí tengo un fetch que recibe datos de php mediante ajax

var a = "algo";
localStorage.setItem("letra", a);

});
```

Luego tengo un html externo, en el que hago referencia al primer archivo js

```
 <script src="./js/Archivo1.js"></script>
```

En el segundo archivo js tengo esto y hace referencia a otro html distinto:

```
    alert(localStorage.getItem('a'));
```

Finalmente, me sale null y he verificado que en inspeccionar > aplicación > almacenamiento local no hay nada. El esquema de lo que quiero hacer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿`localStorage.getItem('a')` o `localStorage.getItem('letra')`?

Comment: Esto "Quiero pasar una variable de un JavaScript a otro" tiene muy poco sentido, puedes explicarlo de otra manera?

Comment: @padaleiana según la sintaxis de la api es así storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);, es como   localStorage.setItem('font', 'Helvetica'); por eso lo de letra y a

Comment: @Yussef he puesto un esquema aclaratorio al final del documento, de un archivo JavaScript quiero pasar una variable a otro archivo JavaScript diferente

Comment: declara la variable a en el primer archivo javascript fuera de cualquier evento (por encima del document.ready). var a = null; // por ejemplo, despues haces las asignaciones que necesites. Tiene que estar disponible en adelante en cualquier archivo javascript que cargues por debajo de este. Es lo que entiendo.

Comment: Por eso... En el ejemplo que diste, tu _keyname_ es _font_, entonces va a ser `localStorage.getItem('font')`. Obtenés el ítem por su clave, no por su valor. Lo podés ver [en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

Comment: He puesto lo que me has dicho @padaleiana y sigue sin ir:

- En archivo 1:
 a = "hola";
 localStorage.setItem(a,"letra");
- En archivo 2:
 alert(localStorage.getItem('a'));

Comment: Tampoco va @Francisco con lo de null y fuera del document ready:

- En archivo 1:
 var a = null;
 a = "hola";
 localStorage.setItem(a,"letra");

- En archivo 2:
 alert(localStorage.getItem('a'));

Comment: Atendé la documentación @IndexOutOfBounds. Los parámetros de [`setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) son `keyName, keyValue`, y el de [`getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) es `keyName`. Si el valor de _a_ es "hola", y querés que tu clave también se llame _a_, ¡entonces es `localStorage.setItem("a", a)`! Tu clave es un *`string`* (de hecho, el valor también es un `string`, pero en el valor es donde va tu variable.)

Comment: Por otra parte, al hacer `a = "hola"; localStorage.setItem(a,"letra");`, tu clave aquí se llama **_hola_**, no _a_, por lo tanto debés hacer `localStorage.getItem(a)` o `localStorage.getItem("hola")` (el cual es el valor de _a_ cuando asignaste esa clave al `localStorage`). Repito: ojo con las claves y los valores, no mezcles código...

Comment: @padaleiana ¡ya me salió!, muchas gracias por la aclaración, de verdad que no lo entendía, gracias otra vez :)